# Ошибка в EF 6.4 The term 'enable-migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, codefirst

Ранее я пользовался подходом code-first и не было не каких проблем. Установлена была версия `EntityFramework` `6.2.0`. Студия предложила обновить до версии `6.4.4`. После обновления я создал новый проект `Win Forms` попробовал включить миграцию командой: `enable-migrations`, но теперь выходит ошибка:

```
> The term 'enable-migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:18
+ enable-migrations <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (enable-migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Но, если сменить версию `EntityFramework` назад на `6.2.0`, всё отлично создаётся и нет ошибки. Подскажите пожалуйста, может кто знает, что сменилось с новой версией `EntityFramework`, что я делаю не так?

***UPDATE:***
Если просто закрыть проект, а потом заного запустить с версией `Entity` `6.4.4`, при старте сразу же в консоли вылезает вот такая вот ошибка:

```
> Missing function body in function declaration.
At D:\WindowsFormsApp2\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\tools\EntityFramework6.PS2.psm1:241 char:5
+      <<<< WarnIfOtherEFs 'Enable-Migrations'
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingFunctionBody
 
Import-Module : The module to process 'EntityFramework6.PS2.psm1', listed in field 'ModuleToProcess' of module manifest 'D:\WindowsForm
sApp2\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\tools\EntityFramework6.PS2.psd1' was not processed because no valid module was found in any module
 directory.
At D:\WindowsFormsApp2\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\tools\init.ps1:11 char:18
+     Import-Module <<<<  (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'EntityFramework6.PS2.psd1')
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (EntityFramework6.PS2:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleFileNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Comment: А если попробовать так EntityFramework6\Enable-migrations ? у меня что подобное было

Comment: @PavelPopov не помогло. А если перезпапустить visual studio то при старте вылезет ошибка в консоль, дополнил в вопросе.

Answer (score 7):

В EF Core миграции включены сразу по умолчанию и такой команды просто нет:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/44057203/5752652

В версии EF 6.3.0 пошли в направлении "облегчим переход на CORE"

> The EF 6.3.0 runtime was released to NuGet in September 2019. The main goal of this release was to facilitate migrating existing applications that use EF 6 to .NET Core 3.0

и вполне возможно, что и удалили эту команду в процессе переписывания кода:

> The migrations commands have been rewritten to

PS Полный changelog/whatsnew тут:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/

---

Update: очень похоже на вот эту ситуацию:

https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/1348

и решение [как и тут](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/1337) такое же - откат на 6.2

В том плане что мне от EF 6 нужна ещё поддержка emdx и она тоже очень сильно хромает, приходится всё чаще шаманить руками в старых проектах -- вижу, что баги в ветке 6.x чинят редко, неохотно и всё внимание на core.

Comment: Получается у меня только вариант использовать 6.2 ? Потому что в WinForm кору я не прикручу не как )

Comment: @Андрей Создайте на 6.2 проект и включите миграции, потом пробуйте обновляться. У нас проекты на 6.4.4 работают, хотя и порой не без проблем.

Comment: EntityCore или обычный? У меня просто на WinForms обычный entity, и на 6.4.4 не работает миграция, на 6.2 всё отлично